# Uninstalling all VSCode plugins / extensions?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to uninstall all vscode plugins at once? I installed a few different HTML plugins, and now it's blowing my HTML markup, so I'd like to reset the entire editor.

Comment: You can also disable all installed extensions - not uninstall - by right clicking the three dots - ellipsis - on the upper right where the file explorer usually is when the extensions icon is activated.

Comment: The name of the command @Mark is talking about is "Disable All Installed Extensions". It is also available from Ctrl-Shift-P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensions are installed in a per user extensions folder. Depending on your platform, the location is in the following folder:

```
Windows %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions
macOS ~/.vscode/extensions
Linux ~/.vscode/extensions
```

You can go to extensions folder and delete all plugins/extensions.
I was try it on macOS and it worked.

Comment: Awesome just tried it on Ubuntu by rm -fr ~/.vscode/extension/* and it worked.  Thanks again!